# Removing a word from the URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change URLs of type:

```
/lang-en/74-home-decoration
```

by:

```
/en/74-home-decoration
```

That is: eliminating *lang-* in some URLs being generated.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^lang-?(.*)$ http://urldemisitio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

I have already resolved it. If it helps someone, it would be:

```
RewriteRule ^lang-(.*)$ http://urldemisitio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Some more explanation would be nice. What is the change here?

Comment: @MeiravLeibowitz oh. Then the question is a typo question and not worth keeping